# LoginController not being called in ASP.Net Core MVC (In Visual Studio Code)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have following controller in asp.net core MVC.

```
public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Callback()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

But when I load in URL like localhost:5000/login/callback.

It calls HomeController's Index Method. What am I doing wrong? In startup.cs I have following in Configure Method.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
```

Hey, Pals. Thanks fo your answers. I forgot to mention that I was running project in visual studio code. So when I ran project in vs2017, it is working now. So may be this is build issue. So now question turns to how to build (or rebuild) project in visual studio code?

Comment: I created here a new asp.net Core project, created a login controller.. and it's working.. take a look https://ibb.co/k9kb1v

Comment: app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

Comment: I have updated question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `Route` for the controller.
Then decorate action either by `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]`

```
[Route("api/MyLogin")]
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Callback()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: By writing "api/MyLogin" does not mean it is Api Controller... In AspNetCore MVC both API and MVC controllers derives from the same base Controller class

Comment: alright ! But this is weird.. I have created a new one here to test and works normal.  ibb.co/k9kb1v -> printscreen

Comment: This is not a valid answer. `[Route]` attribute do overrides conventional routing, and is just another way to define routing in ASP.NET Core. Moreover, it is not needed to add '/api' prefix in this case, as action returns View, it is not an API method, as @ThiagoLoureiro already mentioned